# Pinescript issue between local and global scope

Tags: pine-script

```
if (barstate.islast)
    myLine = line.new(x1=bar_index[SHI], y1=rsi[SHI],
         x2=bar_index[FHI], y2=rsi[FHI], color=color.lime)
         
    line.set_extend(id=myLine, extend=extend.right)
    

alertcondition(condition=crossover(rsi, myLine), title="RSI breakout", message="RSI crossed The Line")
```

I'm drawing a line between certain points on RSI I named the line `myLine` and now I want to add an alert that fires when RSI passes thru that line.

The issue is I can't declare `alertcondition` inside `if statement` local scope and also I can't access `myLine` since it is in the local scope of the `if statement`, what shall I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the `myLine` access problem.
However, it doesn't solve your `crossover()` problem, because that function expects 2 series as arguments.
You're providing a series (`rsi`) and a line object (`myLine`), which will result in an error.
I've commented out that line.

```
//@version=4
study("Test", shorttitle="TST")

var line    myLine      = line.new(na, na, na, na, color=color.lime, extend=extend.right)
var int     SHI         = 30
var int     FHI         = 20

rsi = rsi(close, 14)

if (barstate.islast)
    line.set_xy1(myLine, bar_index[SHI], rsi[SHI])
    line.set_xy2(myLine, bar_index[FHI], rsi[FHI])

plot(rsi)
// alertcondition(condition=crossover(rsi, myLine), title="RSI breakout", message="RSI crossed The Line")
```